# Multihomed windows server 2012 r2 connectivity fails

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 r2 with 2 NICs. 1 local(169.254.1.1/24) and 1 "public"(conected to another local network, 10.0.10.47) interfaces. I have configured DNS, DHCP ONLY on the local interface, and NAT in the public. I have a pc connected to the local network and it gets a correct ip(169.254.1.20) and can make ping to the server local interface, but **I cannot reach the 10.0.10.47 interface from my pc**. I know there are several variables but Ive searched so much sites and didn't found any solution.

More info:

- Both firewalls are disabled(just to remove some variables)
- I can reach internet from my 10.0.10.47 interface, but It doesn't mather because I cannot even reach the 10.0.10.47 ip from my pc.
- Just 1 default gateway configured in each host(that's not the problem), client default gateway: 169.254.1.1, server default gateway: 10.0.10.2.
- All the scenary is running on Hyper-V.
- The pc is running a windows 8 enterprise.

**EDIT >>>>**

- My DNS service resolves internet names to the client, so it is working.

Also Ive followed that guides:

- http://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2013/06/19/network-interface-configuration-for-multihomed-windows-server-2012-directaccess-servers/
- http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/how-to-install-configure-tcpip-routing-in-a-hyper-v-guest/
- I have more links but cannot post it because of my low rep on this site.
- (now I have some rep points, thanks) http://blog.mikejmcguire.com/2013/10/18/controlling-multi-homed-microsoft-dns-server-registration-your-eyes-can-deceive-you-dont-trust-them/

Keep in mind this laboratory is just for testing. I'll be adding more info by demand, I don't know what else data to add. Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**(thanks to @joeqwerty)

I was using an invalid local ip range(169.254.1.1/24). That range is included in the range used by the APIPA protocol(169.254.0.1 through 169.254.255.254) as described here: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html. So it means that my 10.0.10.47 was recieving the pings from the client(169.254.1.20) , but not replying because of that issue.

**LAST EDIT:**

Here is the rfc that says that 169.254/16 range is not routable: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-1.6

Just changed my local range to 192.168.1.1/24 and everything is working ok.

Comment: `1.` If you want the server to act as a router then you'll need to add the RRAS role to the server. `2.` APIPA doesn't configure a default gateway so it isn't a "routable" address range. It's meant for communication confined to a single network. `3.` You should be assigning a "real" ip address configuration to the clients, including the default gateway and DNS servers.

Comment: 1. As I said, I have NAT configured, and in the second link I posted is explained how to configure the RRAS role to the server(I've done the same). 2. It's the first time that I hear about APIPA, but anyways as I said, **I have 1 default gateway per host**, configured by DHCP on the client, and manually on the external/public interface of the server(2nd link). 3. I dont know what did you mean by a "real" ip, but my client has the DNS configured by DHCP to, and has a valid ip. Sorry if I misunderstood any of your points. I'll add some more info.

Comment: In the second point, I meant 1st link.

Comment: Ok...I've been searching about APIPA, I didn't even know that the ip range that I was using was used by that protocol to...so I've changed my local ip range from 169.254.1.1/24 to 192.168.1.1/24 and everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much @joeqwerty!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the server to act as a router then you'll need to add the RRAS role to the server.
2. APIPA doesn't configure a default gateway so it isn't a "routable" address range. It's meant for communication confined to a single network.
3. You should be assigning a "real" ip address configuration to the clients, including the default gateway and DNS servers.